# How is styling of the UI for an IOS Apps done?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, user-interface, uiview, ios7

So with websites on the web we use HTML, CSS and Javascript.

1. What do we actually use to build the UI for an IOS App?
2. Is there a CSS/HTML/JS equivalent use for building IOS Apps?
3. What is the most common way use to design, style the UI of an IOS App?

The reason I ask is because I'm spending longer than expected learning core graphics and would like to move on with the book I'm studying from. I was under the impression core graphics was used for styling of apps and it was like an IOS equivalent of CSS.

Hoping someone could help clear things up thanks.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases, images are used for styling in iOS.

For simple things like just changing background and text colors, UIView and its subclasses have direct accessors.

For most things, you won't need core graphics just for styling purposes. It would be easier to help you if we knew more concretely what you want to achieve, though.

The closest thing to a CSS equivalent is appearance proxies, which allow you to specify things like "all instances of UITextField should look have this font, colors and shadow when contained inside a NavigationController". You can override this for specific instances by just setting the desired values on the instance.

Comment: I'll be building an app for a book club and a large group of people who debate, we will have profiles, groups, news feeds etc. The app will have a UI like linked-in/facebook.

Comment: That's not really a *concrete* example.

Comment: I'm far from the stage where the UI will be designed. I'm still teaching myself cocoa-touch. What I do know is that the app will have feel similar to linked in, facebook. Background colour of my choice, small image icons for links, spinners, loaders, flat style UI. I can't really be too specific at this stage because I just don't know exactly how my UI will look but it will definitely be similar to sites I referenced above. You answered most of my questions. I was concerned about font management also but appearance proxies looks like it will take care of my concerns.

Comment: You'll get quite far with those, and you can of course create your own view classes for more specialized and fancy things. Smaller apps with only standard UI concepts (not necessarily looks) can get by entirely without creating their own view classes just by styling the standard UIKit classes. Remember: Images are your friend, especially `UIImage resizableImage...`.

Comment: I was under the impression that images would slow down the app. I think I'm comparing the way apps run a little too much to the way a website does. I normally like to use as much CSS as possible when designing websites and then images here and there when needed for logos, icons etc.

Comment: Images for buttons etc. are very very fast in iOS. Also, the simulator won't give you a realistic picture regarding performance. So not assume, measure speed, and don't optimize prematurely.